# How to change the CSS property of the DOM element with AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I created a function `validateCode()` and when a user clicks on the button `validateCode()` will trigger.

I want to change the height of the `<div class="loginForm"> </div>` when the button clicks.

I was trying : http://jsfiddle.net/Lvc0u55v/10358/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/vvfnN/216/

Comment: You can also use ngClass - https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClass

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a solution using [ngClass](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClass):

```js
angular
  .module('LoginForm', [])
  .controller('mainController', [function() {
    var self = this;    
    self.validateCode = function() {
      self.setLoginFormModified = true;
  };
}]);
```

```css
.loginForm {
  height:140px;
  width:150px;
  background-color:blue;
}

.loginFormModified {
  height: 500px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<section 
  ng-app="LoginForm"
  ng-controller="mainController as ctrl"
  ng-class="{'loginForm': true, 'loginFormModified': ctrl.setLoginFormModified}">
  
  <button ng-click="ctrl.validateCode()">
    Click me
  </button>      
</section>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is another method you can take into consider too. 
This is suitable for simple style changing. It is suggested to create function to modified multiple styles, if you have more complicated cases.

```css
.loginForm {
  height: 140px;
  width: 150px;
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.7/angular.min.js"></script>
<section class="loginForm" ng-app="LoginForm" 
ng-controller="mainController" ng-style="modified&&{'height':'500px'}">
  <button ng-click="modified=true">
    Click me
  </button>
</section>

<script>
  var app = angular.module('LoginForm', []);
app.controller('mainController',[function(){}]);
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

define two style properties as follow :

```
<style>
.loginFormInitialStyle{
   height:140px;
   width:150px;
   background-color:blue;
}
.loginFormChangeStyle{
   height:500px;
   width:150px;
   background-color:blue;
}
</style>
```

then use ng-class instead of class as follow

```
<div ng-class="loginForm"></div>
```

then define $scope.loginForm object with two properties loginFormInitialStyle and loginFormChangeStyle with default values.

```
$scope.loginForm = {"loginFormInitialStyle":true, loginFormChangeStyle:false}
```

then in your on-click function just change the values of loginFormObject

```
$scope.onClick = function(){
   $scope.loginForm = {"loginFormInitialStyle":false, loginFormChangeStyle:true}
}
```